# Why isn't this unordered list centered? What is wrong?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

Just can't center this list... (elements, li).

What is wrong?

I'm looking at this code almost half hour now, still can't find what is wrong. changing something all the time and still wrong.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-Ua-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <h1 class="hidden">Devloger</h1>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Strona Główna
                </li>
                <li>
                    Spis Treści
                </li>
                <li>
                    Kategorie
                </li>
                <li>
                    Współpraca
                </li>
                <li>
                    Kontakt
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>


</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("2.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#logo {
    background-image: url("logo.png");
    width: 527px;
    height: 58px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.nav {
    background-color: #55585d;
    height: 36px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #44474c;
    border-top: 2px solid #44474c;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.nav > ul li {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That happened because you're floating to the left the li tag, remove it and add use flexbox on the ul, set up a desired width in this case I put 100% and justify-content: center; so it can be centered.

```css
    body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("2.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#logo {
    background-image: url("logo.png");
    width: 527px;
    height: 58px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.nav {
    background-color: #55585d;
    height: 36px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #44474c;
    border-top: 2px solid #44474c;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    width:100%;
}
.nav > ul li {
    text-align: center;
    
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <h1 class="hidden">Devloger</h1>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Strona Główna
                </li>
                <li>
                    Spis Treści
                </li>
                <li>
                    Kategorie
                </li>
                <li>
                    Współpraca
                </li>
                <li>
                    Kontakt
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you float elements then you will have a hard time centering them. Elements with `float` either float left or float right.

Set your `.nav > ul li` to `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` and give the `.nav > ul` a `margin: 0 auto` instead:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#logo {
    width: 527px;
    height: 58px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.nav {
    background-color: #55585d;
    height: 36px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #44474c;
    border-top: 2px solid #44474c;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto; /* changed */
    padding: 0px;
}
.nav > ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block; /* changed */
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Strona Główna
            </li>
            <li>
                Spis Treści
            </li>
            <li>
                Kategorie
            </li>
            <li>
                Współpraca
            </li>
            <li>
                Kontakt
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: "When you float elements then you will have a hard time centering them." 
How Can I center this while still keeping float:left; ? (with hard time)

How to achieve that?

Comment: @AdriannoBarello You can float an element inside a container and then center the container. But really `float` is not the right method for putting those `li` elements on a single line.

Answer (score -1):

change your css only `float:left` to `display:inline-block` coz float left squeezing(floating) your text to left

```
.nav > ul li {
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
```

}

rest is good